# ¿Cómo mantener la selección de un dropdownlist después del post?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo un dropdownlist que lleno desde una llamada Ajax (jQuery).

```
 <select class="custom-select" id="IdProducto" name="IdProducto"></select>
```

La clase que hace de View Model sería algo así:

```
 public class Producto() { 
    public int IdProducto {get; set;}
    public string NomProd {get; set; }
 }
```

El método de acción que obtiene los productos los devuelve en formato Json y el dropdownlist se me rellena correctamente desde una llamada Ajax (jQuery).
Al hacer el post, al método del controlador que ha de gestionar los datos, el modelo le llega correctamente.
El problema es que al volver del post, el dropdownlist no aparece con la selección realizada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar ajax, pero en caso de que necesites hacerlo de la manera que explicas, puedes usar `localStorage` para guardar el valor de tu `select`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let id = localStorage.getItem('IdProductoHelper');
    if(id !== undefined)
        $('#IdProducto option[value=' + id + ']').attr("selected", true);

    $('#IdProducto').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('IdProductoHelper', $(this).value);
    });
});
```

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que recomendaria es que evites realizar un post que recargue la pagina, podrias usar el `$.ajax`

[Web API With AJAX: Submit Form Data After Serialization](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/web-api-with-ajax-submit-form-data-after-serialization/)

de esta forma no perderas el valor seleccionado porque la pagina no se refresca

El punto importante esta en la utilizacion de una llamada ajax cuando se realiza el guardar de los datos del form, en tu caso invocarias al mismo action que usas cuando realizas el submit

```
 $(function() {

    $("#Save").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3413/api/person',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//en el document ready lo que haces es:

$('#IdProducto option[value="POSICION DEL ARRAY"]').attr("selected", true);
```

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor "POSICION DEL ARRAY" del modelo?

Answer (score 0):

Si es con web forms se solucionaría solo colocando la validación `IsPostBack`

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{

...

}
```

Yo tenia el mismo problema y lo he solucionado así.

Saludos.